# Google Visualization Charts Timeline - tooltip dateformat not working

Tags: charts, google-visualization, tooltip, timeline, dateformatter

I'm trying to change the Dateformat in a Google Charts Timeline **tooltip**. For some reason it's not working at all. I've tried this pattern 'dd.MM, yyyy' to change the hAxis via the options which worked just fine, but the tooltip doesn't change.

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Name' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'City' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
  dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
  dataTable.addRows([
     // some php code to echo Rows that look like this
     ['Mike', 'London', new Date(2021,4,25), new Date(2021,5,18)],
     ['Peter', 'Berlin', new Date(2021,3,10), new Date(2021,6,20)]
  ]);

var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: 'dd.MM, yyyy' });
formatter.format(dataTable, 2);
formatter.format(dataTable, 3);

var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById('timeline'));
chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

[Timeline still shows this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDLA3.png)

Comment: the tooltip for Timelines works differently than the other google charts. It displays a range based on the data. The format of the range depends on the date range for the selected row. To customize, you will need to provide a custom tooltip. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55220874/5090771) is an example...